# Define and use a class in an Azure Function

Tags: azure

I'm getting familiar with Azure Function and trying to push some data on the bus to get it catched by another actor... I was wondering how do I define a class and use it inside my csx file... I've also tried to define in the csx file but with no luck

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the Precompiled functions support. This enables you to use .NET assemblies to contain the function implementation, bypassing the dynamic compilation process.

You can find more information here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Precompiled-functions